# How does the public view financing policies by increasing the national debt?

Tags: public-opinion, debt, financing

A response to a comment [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/50765/30575) has caused me to wonder: how does the public view financing government programs by increasing public debt?

To make this a more answerable question, I'm asking for answers based on opinion polls, not opinions of individual users.

Are there any studies showing the likelihood of a populace approving of programs or policies financed by increasing public debt over the same programs or policies being funded by a direct tax increase?

Note that I haven't included a country tag. Seeing that there might not be so many studies on this, I'm keeping the scope broad in that regard. Please explain the scope of the study or survey based on which you are answering.